# Merge Sorting Recurrence Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

If **n = 2<sup>i</sup>**
then proof that **T<sub>n</sub> = 2<sup>n</sup>-1** for merge sorting recurrence. Steps taken to complete the sorting is **n - 1**

The general form is

**T<sub>k</sub> = 2<sup>k</sup> T<sub>n/2<sup>k</sup></sub> + kn - 2<sup>k</sup> + 1**

Please see the image I've attached for more context
[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09y04.jpg)